# how to add a drop down list when user press specific character like @ in a input field?

Tags: javascript, ionic4

currently, I am working on a chat module of a `ionic 4` application where I want to display a drop-down of users when user type `@` inside a chat `ion-textarea` field. once a user clicks on a drop-down value, the user name should be added to textarea. ( It's like comments mention in facebook). how can I implement this?

here is my text area,

```
    <ion-textarea style="height: 50px" class="chat_textarea" placeholder="Text Input"
(ionChange)="contendChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="chatMessage" autofocus></ion-textarea>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tips: go find from user list with prepended `@`.

Comment: @mukyuu thanks for the tip.  what I can't figure out is how can I add a dropdown inside a text-area field.

Comment: I think you can use https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

Comment: like in angular, I can simply add a autocomplete drop drop down with ionic. but it's a standalone drop down. What I want to do is slightly different. basically while user typing a sentence he can mention and tag users in the text itself. something like this https://storage.googleapis.com/igeeksblog/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Tag-People-in-WhatsApp-Chat-on-iPhone.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview.

Then detect if it contain `@` or not:

```
if (value.includes('@')) {
      const filterValue = value.toLowerCase().match(/\@(.*)/);
      return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue[1]));
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ytxsqd?file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.ts)

<sub>I hope you got the idea how to.</sub>

Alternatively:

You could trigger event to summon dropdown or modal on keypress:

```js
$(function() {
    // var e = $.Event('keypress');
    // e.which = 64; // Character '@'
    
    $("#dSuggest").keypress (function (e) {
    if(e.which==64){
      alert('summon');
    }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" id="dSuggest" />
```

Comment: I am not afford to use Jquery. but angular answer was great. I will try to implement it using ionic component. Thank you. @Makyuu.

Comment: @LakshanS It's just an example, but at least you got the idea.